# Create matrix showing proportion of overlap between many polygons

Tags: r, matrix, geospatial, polygon, spatial

I have a list of polygons and I need to know the proportion of overlap of each combination of polygons. In other words proportion of over lap of poly1 to poly2, poly3,... and then poly2 to poly3, poly4,... I have found ways to do this for 2 polygons, but I would like to avoid doing a bunch of pairwise calculations. How can I accomplish this? Also, what can I provide to make this post helpful?

This is an example of code that I used to calculate proportion of overlap of a list of polygons on a single polygon (treatment). Can it be adapted to create a matrix of each poly to poly calculation?

```
###################################################
#read in and create list of polygons
home.names <- list.files("", 
                         pattern="*.shp", recursive=T, full.names=T)
home.names


#####################################################
#create list to hold results and loop home-range overlap calculations
all.home.ranges <- list()

#loop
for (i in 1:length(home.names)){
  home.range <- st_read(home.names[i])
  home.range.t <- st_transform(home.range,'+proj=utm +zone=14 
        +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
  home.range$Area.ha <- st_area(home.range.t)*0.0001
  pi <- st_intersection(treatment, home.range.t) # treatment is a polygon
  if(nrow(pi) != 0){
    home.range$Treat.Overlap.per <- as.numeric(st_area(pi) / st_area(home.range.t) *100)
  } else {
    home.range$Treat.Overlap.per <- 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to construct a matrix with 2 columns. For example, if you have 5 polys:

```
i <- rep(1:5, each=5)
j <- rep(1:5, 5)
comp <- cbind(i, j)[i < j, ]
comp
#       i j
#  [1,] 1 2
#  [2,] 1 3
#  [3,] 1 4
#  [4,] 1 5
#  [5,] 2 3
#  [6,] 2 4
#  [7,] 2 5
#  [8,] 3 4
#  [9,] 3 5
# [10,] 4 5
```

Loop though `comp` and use `i` and `j` to select the two polys for that comparison. Without reproducible data I can't debug this but something like:

```
for (k in 1:nrow(comp){
  home.range <- st_read(home.names[comp[k, 1]])
  home.range.t <- st_transform(home.range,'+proj=utm +zone=14 
        +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
  home.range$Area.ha <- st_area(home.range.t)*0.0001

  home.range2 <- st_read(home.names[comp[k, 2]])
  home.range.t2 <- st_transform(home.range2,'+proj=utm +zone=14 
        +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
  home.range2$Area.ha <- st_area(home.range.t2)*0.0001

  pi <- st_intersection(home.range.t, home.range.t2)
  if(nrow(pi) != 0){
    home.range$Treat.Overlap.per <- as.numeric(st_area(pi) / st_area(home.range.t) *100)
  } else {
    home.range$Treat.Overlap.per <- 0
  }
```

The main difference is that the percent overlap could be based on both home.range and home.range2. You could compute both depending on what you are planning to do with the results.

Comment: This sounds promising, but my limited skills have had me trying to figure out how to set up the loop. I do appreciate your time.

Comment: The revised answer may be enough to get you started.